# IronRouter waitOn, data and onAfterAction mess

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I have the following routing:

```
this.route('postsPanel', {
        path: 'posts/:_id',
        waitOn: function() {
            return Meteor.subscribe('posts', this.params._id);
        },
        data: function () {
            return Posts.findOne(this.params._id);
        },
        onAfterAction: function () {
            // Changes to reactive variables based on this.params._id that implicitly affect DOM.
            setTimeout(function () {
               // JQuery code for manipulating affected DOM elements.
               });
             }, 0);
        }
);
```

Problem 1:
Without the timeout function, JQuery code is asynchronously executed before the template is rebuilt and DOM elements can't be accessed / found.
I also tried rendered function with and without timeout function with even bigger delay and it doesn't work.

```
Template.postsPanel.rendered = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
    // JQuery code to manipulate DOM.
    }, 100);

}
```

Where is DOM manipulation code suppose to be, if I want to do it after the site is fully rendered and just moments before user see it?

Problem 2:
Inside template helpers I defined a method getActivePost. It is executed twice, after each data:function() in Iron Router is called. That means the first time its executed, its empty and returns undefined error. My workaround is return this.activePost ? this.activePost : null; 
How to achieve this without defensive programming?

```
Template.postsPanel.helpers({
    getActivePost: function () {
        return this.activePost;
    },
```

I also tried with:

```
Router.configure({
    loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});

Router.onBeforeAction('loading');
```

And it still doesn't work.

What is actually going on behind the scenes? The functions are called this way:

- onWait
- onAfterAction
- data (empty)
- rendered
- data (arrived)

Is there any function that is called after data (arrived)? Where can I manipulate the DOM and make some more changes, before the user sees the page? How to achieve that template helpers actually wait for data? How to manipulate DOM after data arrives?

All this behaviour appears only on refreshing a page. If I enter a route through a href, everything is executed correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `waitOn` function should return the handle to the subscription, otherwise will the loading hook not function properly.